# R library(openxlsx) Error: Workbook has no worksheets

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, xlsx

I am curious whether any of you experienced a similar error while reading an xlsx document in R:

```
library(openxlsx) 
data = read.xlsx(file, sheet =1, startRow = 2, colNames = FALSE)
```

Even when my file has a worksheet an error occurs:

```
Error in read.xlsx.default(file, sheet =1, startRow = 2, colNames = FALSE) : 
  Workbook has no worksheets
```

When I manually added another empty worksheet to my xlsx file, all was OK. However, I would like to know how to solve this issue without opening each xlsx file one by one to add another sheet. Do you have any idea how to deal with it? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Creating a new xlsx file with only one sheet (named Sheet1), `read.xlsx` reads it just fine.

Comment: Are you using up to date version of R and openxlsx?

Answer (score 8):

Did you download the xlsx from the internet? If so, it is probably locked against changes.

Just now I encountered the same error. I could open the xlsx-file in Excel just fine, saw one sheet, I could even read out the sheet name with getSheetNames(). But using read.xlsx gave the error. I then opened it in Excel (2010), allowed editing (the yellow bar below the menus) and saved it. This did do the trick.